# Generating Reports in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner in VB.NET. I have made a small project and now i would like to make some reports to complete the project.

Can anyone please tell me as to how i can work with reports in VB.NET. I want to retrieve data from SQL Server 2000 using Stored Procedures and generate a report in VB.NET.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at Microsoft Report Viewer - it has a wysiwyg design interface and can consume many different types of data.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CC96C246-61E5-4D9E-BB5F-416D75A1B9EF).

Comment: Can i use this with Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Yes - In most retail versions of VS you can create a Report Project. If you are using VS Express there is a free designer add in for 2008 - not sure about 2005 though. The 2005 Redist for your app users is here - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a166cac-758d-45c8-b637-dd7726e61367&DisplayLang=en